# What is the best way to refresh a simple div below using AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm having trouble making the element that displays the value, live, from the DB update via AJAX.

This app, is supposed to take a number, add 1 to it, save the new value and display the updated value, live to the user. It is a simple counter based off of AJAX.

Objective: I need to get the {{ number_post }} number to reflect the recently changed value in the DB, live, without having to refresh the entire page.

What is the best way of doing this?

## Views.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.template import Context, loader
    from home.models import DeathNum
    import datetime
    import time






    def index(request):
            counter = DeathNum.objects.get(pk=1)
            return render(request,
                         'home/basenum.html',
                          {'number_post': str(counter.deaths)}
                          )

    def counterf(repeat):
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)
            counter = DeathNum.objects.get(pk=1)
            counter.deaths += 1
            counter.save()
            print('Added @ %s ' % datetime.datetime.utcnow())
            time.sleep(5)
        return redirect(index)
```

## basenum.html:

```
    {% extends "home/index.html" %}
    {% block content %}
     <br />
      <div class="banner">
       <div class="bannerNum">
          <p div class="numberOf">
              Number of deaths in Blank since 1999:
         </p id="number1">
            <br /><br /><br />
           <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/counter"><p id="h2s">Please 
   click here to see the live counter...</h2></a>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
    <div class="death-div">
  <p class="death1">
     {{ number_post }}
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
      </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

## models.py

```
     from django.db import models

     # Create your models here.
     class DeathNum(models.Model):

         deaths = models.IntegerField()


         def __str__(self):
             return "{0}/{1}\n".format(self.id, self.deaths)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about django, but for ajax and jquery, here's the solution comes to my mind:
for ajax if you are calling your service as "Post" we have:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Your service's URL",
  data: "Your enteries, you can make an object for that",
  success: function(result){
      $('.death1').html(result);
    },
error:function(){
alert('error has occured');
}
    });
```

**UPDATE:**

As stated by user @31piy the Ajax syntax has been updated , and 'success' and 'error' are deprecated, although you can still use them, it's better to change our code like this :

```
$.ajax({ cache: false,
  type: "POST",
  url: "Your service's URL",
  data: "Your enteries, you can make an object for that",

}).done(function (result) {

    $('.death1').html(result);

}).fail(function(event) {

    alert(event.status);

});
```

on ajax success, we have result as an entry which can be a string or an object (you can modify your service's return data in success section);

whenever you call this function, it calls your service and update the DOM which has "death1" class.

if your service works with GET, you should change the type to GET and instead of data, you should pass the parameters by query string.
Hope it will helps you.

Comment: `success` and `error` callbacks are deprecated. Use `.done`, `.fail`, or `.then` to handle returned promise.

Comment: @31piy I appreciate it, it was a notable point, if you want , you can update my answer , or you can tell me to do that :)

Comment: Yes, please update your answer. Using outdated code doesn't help future readers.